# Bounding the values of angles from their cosines relationship

Tags: trigonometry

If the ratio of cosines of 2 angles are bounded from above, can we conclude that the ratio of the angles are bounded as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider the angles $x$ and $x^2$. On any interval bordering zero, the cosines both approach $1$ and so does the ratio of the cosines, but the ratio of $x$ over $x^2$ approaches infinity.